# How can I write this in a more formal way?

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

Is there a **formal** way to say "**from the horse's mouth**"?

Comment: *From the equine's oral cavity*. Also, see http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/straight+from+horse+mouth

Comment: @Silenus And as we all know: *A slight inclination of the cranium, is as adequate as the closing of one ovule, to an equine devoid of its visionary capacity*.

Answer (score 2):

Information that you get **straight from the horse's mouth** means information that you get **from a reliable source**.

> [**Origin**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/336400.html) - I**n horse racing circles** tips on which horse is a likely winner circulate amongst punters. The most trusted authorities are considered to be those in closest touch with the recent form of the horse, that is, stable lads, trainers etc. The notional 'from the horse's mouth' is supposed to indicate one step better than even that inner circle, that is, the horse itself.
>
> [**from the horse's mouth**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+horse%27s+mouth) -  from an authoritative or dependable source, from someone who has the facts.
>
> - "I know it's true! I heard it straight from the horse's mouth!"
> - "Are you sure she's leaving? Definitely, I heard it straight from the horse's mouth.

To answer your question, you can say it formally **"from an authoritative source"** or, not so formally, **"from someone who knows the facts"**.

Comment: I always thought it was a reference to the health/age of the horse: factors one can assess from its mouth. You *sure* races are involved?

Comment: @Mari-LouA There you are. :)

Comment: @TheNate I have edited and added the origin.

Comment: Sidenote: it's not just a *reliable* source, it's from the *original*, *primary*, *first-hand* source. At the very headwaters of the river.

Answer (score 0):

Phrases: 'From the first hand' or 'first hand information' alternative synonyms are: primary (info), eyewitnessed information.

Comment: This site expects references to support suggestions.  It also expects properly punctuated English (especially in answers), since it is "site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like these:

- from the official source.
- from the authoritative source.
- the documented way is to..
- the recommended way is to...

Answer (score -1):

I heard it from the horses mouth / I heard it from the source.
This refers to hearing it from the originator, not just someone in authority.
See the phrase finder as to the origin of the phrase